# How can I insert call duration of an Asterisk call into my own database?

Tags: asterisk

I have my own database to log the calls in astreisk. I need to insert call duration of every call into a table. How can I do this? Can I do this in my dialplan?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are not giving much information about what db backend you would like to use, and also if you are asking about how to write yourself the call duration or how to configure asterisk to write the cdr in question.

So, *generally* speaking, you have 3 possible options for this (see below). For options **2** and **3** you would have to open the connection to the database yourself, write the queries needed to insert/update whatever row(s) needed, handle errors, etc. While for option **1** you just need to configure asterisk to do the job.

1) Asterisk can do this by default on its own, by writing the CDR (Call Detail Record) of every call to a backend. This backend can be [csv](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+cdr+csv), [mysql](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+cdr+mysql), [pgsql](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+cdr+pgsql), [sqlite](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+cdr+sqlite) and other databases through the [cdr_odbc](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+cdr+odbc) module. You have to configure your **cdr.conf** (and depending on the backend you chose, **cdr_mysql.conf**, **cdr_odbc.conf**, **cdr_pgsql.conf** with your backend information, like credentials, table names, etc).

The CDR will be written by default with some contents, which are the CDR Variables (taken from [the predefined asterisk variable list](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+Detailed+Variable+List))

> If the channel has a cdr, that cdr record has it's own set of
>   variables which can be accessed just like channel variables. The
>   following builtin variables are available and, unless specified,
>   read-only.

The ones interesting for you at this point would be:

```
${CDR(duration)}     Duration of the call.
${CDR(billsec)}  Duration of the call once it was answered.
${CDR(disposition)}  ANSWERED, NO ANSWER, BUSY
```

When disposition is ANSWER, **billsec** will contain the number of seconds to bill (the total "answered time" of the call), and duration will hold the total time of the call, including non-billed time.

2) If, on the other hand, if you are not asking about the cdr, but want to write yourself the call duration, you can have an [AGI](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+AGI) script that after issuing a [dial()](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+cmd+Dial), reads the **CDR(billsec)** variable, or the **ANSWEREDTIME** (set by the [Dial()](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+cmd+Dial) command):

```
${DIALEDTIME} * Time for the call (seconds)
${ANSWEREDTIME} * Time from dial to answer (seconds)
```

3) You can also achieve the same result by having an [AMI](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+manager+API) client listening for the event **VarSet** for the variable **ANSWEREDTIME**. The event in question will contain the channel for which this variable has been set.

So, options 2 and 3 are clearly more useful if you already have an AGI script or an AMI client of your own controlling/handling calls, and option 1 is more generic but maybe slightly less flexible.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I'm sorry that I didn't give enough information. The option 2 and 3 is what I need. But I have a question: Is it possible to access ANSWEREDTIME in dialplan?

Comment: @Karadous Sure. See: http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+variables. So just use ${ANSWEREDTIME} and (possible) use the option g of the dial command.

Comment: Very good answer.  Just for completeness sake, for option (1), you may want to mention cdr_adaptive_odbc instead of cdr_odbc, which is more flexible for user defined data.

Comment: @marcelog, but how to get the call duration of B-leg (outbound call from Dialplan)?